# Event Designators in bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, unix, history

Is it possible to use Event Designators for history such as

```
   !!
   !n
   !-n
   !string
```

in bash scripts?

For example:

I have a variable, which keeps my input from command line in it. Also I have a tmp history. Every command which is executed inside my script is stored in this history and command

```
   history
```

work perfectly.

If I type

```
   !!
```

error occures: "!!: command not found".

Answer (score 1):

History expansion is turned on by default only for interactive shells. For the non-interactive shell that runs your script, you would have to turn it on explicitly at the beginning of your script with `set -H`.